# How can I fix Error 149 in Gams?(Uncontrolled set entered as constant)

Tags: gams-math

I have this situation in GAMS:

```
sets
   i index of resource location  /i1*i6/
   j index of disaster location  /j1*j7/
;

...

binary variable x(i,j);

parameter 
   M(j)  /j1 5,j2 4,j3 6,j4 7,j5 6,j6 2,j7 1/
   ch(i) /i1 10,i2 5,i3 10,i4 15,i5 6,i6 12/
;
...

equations 
...

co8(i) 
;

co8(i)..M(j)=l=sum(j,ch(i)*x(i,j));
```

and `co8(i)` give me the error 149  Uncontrolled set entered as constant.

I searched,but I did not find solution.
How can I fix it?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `j` in `M(j)` is not controlled. So, it depends on what you want to do, how to fix this. E.g. if you want a sum over all `j`, you should add that sum (`sum(j,M(j))`). Or do you want this equation for every `j`? Then adjust the declaration and definition accordingly.

Comment: Thanks,I want this equation for every j. how to fix it?

Comment: Declare and define it as `co8(i,j)`. Though, you will get errors for the RHS, since you cannot define the equation for every `j` and sum over all `j`s at the same time. If you want to do that, you need to introduce an Alias for `j` (see: https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/UG_SetDefinition.html#INDEX_alias_22_statement)